Prevent Redirection in ReactJS
I'm using shadcn/ui in my React Remix app, and I'm trying to prevent it from redirecting to another page when I click to open a dialog. I want the redirection to still work when I click on it, but I want to prevent the page from redirecting when I intend to open the dialog
Codesandbox ----> https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/shadcn-ui-vite-forked-mptc3y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A17%2C2-41%2C13
 <div className="flex flex-col border-solid border rounded-md mt-10">
    {data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <a href={`/inbox/${item.id}`}>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-2 p-3 text-left text-sm transition-all w-full border-b hover:shadow-md cursor-pointer">
              <div className="flex w-full flex-col gap-1">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <div className="font-semibold">{item.name}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="flex w-full flex-col gap-1">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <ApproveDialog id={"some test"} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>


That is the work of an a tag, a simple fix will be to change it to a div/button and add an onClick handler.

There's a reason it is recommended not to place interactive elements like buttons inside/within other interactive elements like anchor tags. You could try stopping the click event propagation of the dialog open button from propagating up the DOMTree and hitting the anchor tag, but I couldn't get this to work as expected in your sandbox (which I suspect may be due to how the Dialog components are implemented).
The logical solution is to un-nest these interactive elements so they can function normally as expected in isolation from one another. Refactor the Inbox UI a bit to render the ApproveDialog outside the link.
Example:
const data = [ .... ];

export default function Inbox() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Inbox ({data.length})</h1>

      <div className="flex flex-col border-solid border rounded-md mt-10">
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className="flex flex-col items-start gap-2 p-3 text-left text-sm transition-all w-full border-b hover:shadow-md cursor-pointer">
              <a href={`/inbox/${item.id}`} className="flex w-full flex-col gap-1">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <div className="font-semibold">{item.name}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
                
              <div className="flex w-full flex-col gap-1">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <ApproveDialog id={"some test"} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

The rendered content remains visually identical, but now the button is rendered outside the link and won't interfere with navigation when all you are trying to do is open the modal/dialog.



Alternative
Update the logic to make the Dialog component fully controlled and totally prevent the default action on the Button component.
Example:
export default function ApproveDialog({ id }: { id: string }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setIsOpen(true);
          }}
          size="sm"
          className="rounded-full"
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Ready to send?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Do you want to send this message to the recipient?
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <DialogFooter>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button
              size="sm"
              className="bg-success hover:bg-success text-white"
              type="submit"
              onClick={async () => {
                const response = await fetch("/api/approve", {
                  method: "POST",
                  body: JSON.stringify({ id }),
                });
                if (!response.ok) {
                  alert("error");
                  return;
                }
                alert("success");
              }}
            >
              <Send size={15} className="mr-2" /> Send
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button size="sm" variant={"outline"}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}


Thanks Drew. I have updated my codesandbox. Right now I can click the button and the dialog opens, that's good. However if I wanted to click anywhere on the div, I need to make the redirect work, right now it doesn't work. btw, i'm just using shadcn style of using the dialog. https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/dialog

@Joseph The problem with making the entire "card" the anchor tag is that the other button is necessarily rendered within it and breaks HTML semantics. The third screenshot highlights where exactly the anchor tag is exists/"takes up space" and is clickable. Yes, now some area(s) of the card no longer are clickable for navigation purposes. The alternative I'd suggest is to move the dialog button elsewhere, like to the end of the card to the right. This is basically just a UI/UX design problem at this point.

@Joseph No, something more like move the button outside the clickable card, e.g. something like [ this is the clickable card and anchor link ] ( send button ) or [[ this is the clickable area and anchor link] ( send button )] for each mapped row.

Sorry we can’t do it since that’s the UI requirement.Let’s do this instead. Can you do this?
Try stopping the click event propagation when clicking the button that opens the Dialog
And also change the implementation of the Dialog where we’ll remove the Button there? I think the Button inside of the dialog is the cause why even stopping the propagation doesnt work. Will this work?

@Joseph Found a bit of a hacky workaround.

Try bellow code
App.tsx
export default function Inbox() {
 const data = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "hello",
   },
 ];

 return (
   <div>
     <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Inbox ({data.length})</h1>
     <div className="flex flex-col mt-10 border border-solid rounded-md">
       {data.map((item) => {
         return (
           <div key={item.id}>
             <div
               onClick={(e) => {
                 window.location.href = "sign-in";
               }}
             >
               <div className="flex flex-col items-start w-full gap-2 p-3 text-sm text-left transition-all border-b cursor-pointer hover:shadow-md">
                 <div className="flex flex-col w-full gap-1">
                   <div className="flex items-center">
                     <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                       <div className="font-semibold">{"item.name"}</div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div className="flex flex-col w-full gap-1">
                   <div className="flex items-center">
                     
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         );
       })}
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}

ApproveDialog.tsx
export default function ApproveDialog({ id }: { id: string }) {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          size="sm"
          className="rounded-full"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Ready to send?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Do you want to send this message to the recipient?
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <DialogFooter>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button
              size="sm"
              className="text-white bg-success hover:bg-success"
              type="submit"
              onClick={async () => {
                const response = await fetch("/api/approve", {
                  method: "POST",
                  body: JSON.stringify({ id }),
                });
                if (!response.ok) {
                  alert("error");
                  return;
                }
                alert("success");
              }}
            >
              <Send size={15} className="mr-2" /> Send
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button size="sm" variant={"outline"}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

Update your DialogOverlay as bellow:
(Dialog.tsx)

const DialogOverlay = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof DialogPrimitive.Overlay>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DialogPrimitive.Overlay>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DialogPrimitive.Overlay
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "fixed inset-0 z-50 bg-black/80  data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-0 data-[state=open]:fade-in-0",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }}
  />
))
DialogOverlay.displayName = DialogPrimitive.Overlay.displayName
 


As much as possible. I want to avoid modifying the Dialog.tsx cause it might be reuse by other components too. Maybe we could add but not modify its behavior.

So you can also build separate dialog ( as shadcn already did in Dialog.tsx ) and make those changes in it

A <a> tag is probably not the best fit for what you are trying to achieve as it is intended to be a hyperlink that navigates elsewhere. Using another tag like button might be a better idea in this case.
However, if you really want to stop the a tag from navigating away, you may want to include a onClick={ev => ev.preventDefault()} on that a tag.
Check out ev.preventDefault() documentation.

I still want the redirection to work when I click on it. But I want to prevent from redirecting the page when I want to open the dialog.

Just use the ev.preventDefault() based on your conditions then and it should work..

Can you fork my codesandbox? I tried and still doesn’t work
